# Laravel Horizon Long Wait Detection Setup - Not able to extend wait time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-notification, laravel-horizon

I am using Laravel 5.6 and Horizon 2.0. My Horizon setup is as follows:

config/horizon.php

```
    'waits' => [
        'redis:default' => 600,
        'redis:default_long' => 600,
        'redis:drip_feed' => 600,
        'redis:wms' => 600,
    ],
```

- With my setup being `connection_name:queue_name => time_seconds`

HorizonServiceProvider.php

```
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

         Horizon::routeSlackNotificationsTo('https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx', '#redis_queue');
    }
```

Horizon however seems to be ignoring this and sending me notifications when any queue extends the default 60 seconds wait time.

I have fully rebooted horizon including:

- clearing cache
- clear and store config cach
- php artisan horizon:terminate/reset/purge
- restarted server
- restarted daemon supervisord

Is there something else I need to do in order to get these settings to persist, or maybe something else in mysetup?

I did previously upgrade from Horizon 1 but did remove this first before installing 2. Im not sure if there could be some legacy code causing issues?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but for everyone who came across this issue, here is a possible solution.

If you have more than one queue per supervisor, then you have to specify the queues combined:

```
    'waits' => [
        'redis:default,default_long,drip_feed,wms' => 600,
    ],
```